# python3 read text file into seperate dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to figure out how to read the following example text file into a dictionary per block using the day as the key and the rest as the value, but I can't work it out:

```
Friday
10:00 - 10:30    Debrief
10:30 - 13:00    Track running
13:00 - 14:00    Lunch
14:00 - 18:00    Track running
18:00            End

Saturday
10:00 - 10:30    Debrief
10:30 - 13:00    Track running
13:00 - 14:00    Lunch
14:00 - 18:00    Track running
18:00            End

Sunday
10:00 - 10:30    Debrief
10:30 - 13:00    Track running
13:00 - 14:00    Lunch
14:00 - 18:00    Track running
18:00            End
```

This should produce 3 dictionaries with keys Friday, Saturday and Sunday, the rest of each block should be the value of the keys.

This is what I have started to do, but I am stuck on how to use the text from the text file as the dictionary key plus this looks really cumbersome, is there an easy way to do this or am I on the right lines anyway?:

```
def schedule():
    flag = False
    with open("example.txt", 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if len(line.strip()) == 0:
                flag = True
            elif flag:
                # somehow use the day of the week to 
                # become the dictionary key
                flag = False
            else:
                # somehow use the rest of the block of text as the value
```

I'm sorry I don't have any working code

Answer (score 0):

Well this is an example I threw quickly, obviously the code can be improved, it creates a dictionary with keys of the day week, and each day has a list of each task in schedule.

```
def schedule():
flag = False
schedule = dict()
days_of_week = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", 
                "Saturday", "Sunday"]

with open("example.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line_items = line.split()
        if line_items and line_items[0] in days_of_week:
            schedule[line_items[0]] = list()
            current_day = line_items[0]
        else:
            if line_items and current_day:
                schedule[current_day].append(line_items)

return schedule
```

This would result in:

```
{'Sunday': [['10:00', '-', '10:30', 'Debrief'], ['10:30', '-', '13:00', 'Track', 'running'], ['13:00', '-', '14:00', 'Lunch'], ['14:00', '-', '18:00', 'Track', 'running'], ['18:00', 'End']], 'Friday': [['10:00', '-', '10:30', 'Debrief'], ['10:30', '-', '13:00', 'Track', 'running'], ['13:00', '-', '14:00', 'Lunch'], ['14:00', '-', '18:00', 'Track', 'running'], ['18:00', 'End']], 'Saturday': [['10:00', '-', '10:30', 'Debrief'], ['10:30', '-', '13:00', 'Track', 'running'], ['13:00', '-', '14:00', 'Lunch'], ['14:00', '-', '18:00', 'Track', 'running'], ['18:00', 'End']]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar approach to what Ilhicas did in terms of using a dictionary containing the days of the week. I took it one step further and was able to have a string of the required information for the 'value' of each dictionary entry.

```
with open('example.txt', 'r') as f:
    dictDays = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday']
    lines = f.read().splitlines()  #read lines but removes '\n'
    schDict = {}
    for text in lines:
        if text in dictDays:
            schDict.update({text: ''})
            del lines[lines.index(text)]
    connect = ['']
    count = 0
    for text in lines:
        if text != '':
            connect[count] += (text + '\n')
        if text == '':
            connect.append('')
            count += 1
    for txtNum in range(len(connect)):
        dayKey = list(schDict.keys())[txtNum]
        schDict.update({dayKey:connect[txtNum]})

print(schDict)
```

I too am new to Python. I've been working with it for roughly 2 months so I'm sure this block of code could get cleaned up a bit but it should contain the tools you need to solve your problem.

Comment: I can't get this to work unfortunately, if gives list out of range

Comment: Hmm? That is interesting. I just copied and pasted the above code into a new .py file in Atom, made sure the open function was pointing to the correct file location and ran it just fine. This is the output I get: 
`{'Friday': '10:00 - 10:30    Debrief\n10:30 - 13:00    Track running\n13:00 - 14:00    Lunch\n14:00 - 18:00    Track running\n18:00            End\n', 'Saturday': '10:00 - 10:30    Debrief\n10:30 - 13:00    Track running\n13:00 - 14:00    Lunch\n14:00 - 18:00    Track running\n18:00`
I shortened the output due to character restrictions but you get the idea.

Comment: 'list out of range' occurs when you are trying to run a for loop through an empty list. Are you copying and pasting the code from above or modifying it a little? If I can see the code I can help trouble shoot.

Comment: @iFunction were you able to get the code to work? was my post helpful?